# How to authenticate for Google Analytics on AWS Ubuntu without browser

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, authentication, google-analytics, ubuntu-16.04

I have been pulling Google Analytics metrics using the following code in R on my local machine

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
client_id <- " "
client_secret <- " "
oauth_token <- Auth(client_id,client_secret)
save(oauth_token, file="oauth_token")
load("oauth_token")
GetProfiles(oauth_token)
query.init<-Init()
```

It prompts to authenticate only for the first time.

Similarly, when I try to pull Google Analytics metrics with same code in R on AWS Ubuntu instance, it prompts the following:

```
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Please point your browser to the following url:
```

How do I authenticate in an AWS UBUNTU instance to pull Google Analytics metrics? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied oauth_token and .httr-oauth files from my local machine to AWS instance, commented out lines 4,5 and that's it. I am able to pull the Google Analytics metrics.